# How to fetch particular column data and display it on JSP page using Hibernate JPA join query

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have started learning Spring Boot, Hibernate and JPA, Could not able to figure out how to display particular column data on JSP page fetched from join query.

Below added my java code, If I run my JSP page i'm getting output as

> [Ljava.lang.Object;@59a966cb

I need to display productName and producttype on my JSP page, Can anyone please help me to achieve this

**ProductMasterModel**

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_master")
public class ProductMasterModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productId;

    public ProductMasterModel() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ProductMasterModel(String productName, int productCategoryId) {
        super();
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;


    }

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "product_category_id")
    private int productCategoryId;

      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumn(name = "product_category_id", referencedColumnName = "product_catogory_id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private ProductCatagoryMasterModel productCatagoryMasterModel; 

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getProductCategoryId() {
        return productCategoryId;
    }

    public void setProductCategoryId(int productCategoryId) {
        this.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;
    }  

}
```

**ProductCategoryMasterModel**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="product_catagory")
public class ProductCatagoryMasterModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="product_catogory_id")
    private int productCategoryId;

    public ProductCatagoryMasterModel() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ProductCatagoryMasterModel(String productType) {
        super();
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    @Column(name="product_type")
    private String productType;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "productCatagoryMasterModel")
    private ProductMasterModel productMasterModel;

    public int getProductCategoryId() {
        return productCategoryId;
    }

    public void setProductCategoryId(int productCategoryId) {
        this.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }   

}
```

**ProductMasterRepository**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.lollipop.model.ProductMasterModel;

@Repository
public interface ProductMasterRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductMasterModel, Integer> {


      @Query (value = "select pm.productName,p.productType from ProductMasterModel pm join pm.productCatagoryMasterModel p") 
      public List<Object[]> getProductCategoryDetail();

}
```

**ProductService**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductCategoryRepository productCategoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductMasterRepository productMasterRepository;

      public List<Object[]> getProductCat() {
         return productMasterRepository.getProductCategoryDetail();

         }
}
```

**ProductController**

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;


    @RequestMapping("/addproduct")
    public String addProduct(ProductMasterModel productMasterModel,HttpServletRequest request) {

        productService.getProductCat();
        List<Object[]> productlist= productService.getProductCat();      
        request.setAttribute("product",productlist);
        return "ajaxcall.jsp";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="productdetail">
<c:forEach var="product" items="${product}">
${product}
</c:forEach>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `addProduct` controller method you are setting productList to the request object. Which is not right.

Follow this guide to set it up right - https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jsp-view-example/

Comment: I tried adding Map by seeing the example you shared, still getting same result, if possible can you please post solution by editing my code, that would be very helpful, thanks in advance